# How to store json response into variable?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting json response from api. I need to store into variable using model,how can i store?

```
struct StructLogin {
    var status:String?
    var contentarr = [content]()
}
struct content {
    var AuthoToken:String?
    var user_name:String?
    var user_type:String?
}

let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
StructLoginObj.status = jsonResponse!["status"] as? String
StructLoginObj.contentarr = contentArray

contentObj.AuthoToken = jsonResponse!["auth_token"] as? String
contentObj.user_name = jsonResponse!["user_name"] as? String
contentObj.user_type = jsonResponse!["user_type"] as? String
```

> {"status":"200","content":{"user_type":"1","user_name":"Super Admin","auth_token":"7500b440c0f8035e864e1541c650b888"}}

Comment: struct StructLogin {
    var status:String?
    var contentarr = [content]()
}
struct content {
    var AuthoToken:String?
    var user_name:String?
     var user_type:String?
}
How can store through model?

Comment: Please, fix your question. It's hard to see your code.

Comment: JSON response is a variable itself. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`Codable`** to parse your `JSON` response into an object.

```
struct Login: Codable {
    var status: String?
    var content:Content?

}
struct Content: Codable {
    var auth_token:String?
    var user_name:String?
    var user_type:String?
}
```

Let's take the example of `JSON` response provided by you.

```
let str = """
{"status":"200","content":{"user_type":"1","user_name":"Super Admin","auth_token":"7500b440c0f8035e864e1541c650b888"}}
"""
```

Since we don't have the actual `Data` from `API`, we'll be converting `str` to `data` for parsing.

```
if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    let login = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Login.self, from: data)
    print(login)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Codable` for easy convert the object to data , also your `content` key is a dictionary not an array

**Save:**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = try! decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)  
print(res.content)
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(res.content)
// save data anywhere e.x userDefaults if it's a settings 

 UserDefaults.shared.set(data,forKey:"User")
```

**Read:**

```
if let data = UserDefaults.shared.data(forKey:"User") {
  print(data)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let content: Content
} 
struct Content: Codable {
    let userType, userName, authToken: String 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()` method to convert `API` return value to `JavaScript` object :

```
let result = JSON.parse(data);
```